# How to conditionally apply css to differently nested content

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using sass and the structure of the page is not easily changed.

I have the following structure because my header is two different sizes depending on the page of the site users are visiting:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div id="large-header"></div> (or <div id="small-header"></div>)
  </div>
  <div class="full-screen-menu"></div>
</div>
```

I want full screen menu to either be 50px or 100px depending on if `.header > #small-header` or `.header > #large-header` so that the header is still visible with the full screen menu. Ideally I'd be able to use a conditional like

```
.container {
  @if .header > #large-header {
    .full-screen-menu {
      top: 100px;
    }
  } @else {
    .full-screen-menu {
      top: 50px;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't use if statements and I also don't know a way to check a conditional traversing up the DOM of one `div` and have it apply to a `div` further down the page that share a common parent.

Do you have any ideas for how I could accomplish this?

Comment: You can't do that. I would just put a class on the `<div class="header large-header"></div>` that way you can access and style `full-screen-menu`

Comment: better just put it like this imho `.container .container--large-header` or  `.container .container--small-header` and then you can control anything that might change because of the header in your container

Comment: Wouldn't you still have to apply that `large-header` class to the `container` in order to properly target `#full-screen-menu`?
Edit: posted before seeing Dirk's comment

Comment: also SCSS is pre-processed you can check the DOM to render the correct html thats not how this works :)

Comment: @RobinClower to answer your question, with your html structure, you can have the class on `.header` and be able to target the `full-screen-menu` but it would be better to put it on the container. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCSS:

```
.container {
  .header {
     height:100px;
  }

  .full-screen-menu {
     height:100px;
  }

  &--small-header {
    .header {
      height:50px;
    }

    .full-screen-menu {
      height:50px;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container .header {
  height: 100px;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}

.container .full-screen-menu {
  top: 100px;
  background:rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
}

.container--small-header .header {
  height: 50px;
}

.container--small-header .full-screen-menu {
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="full-screen-menu">MENU</div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="container container--small-header">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="full-screen-menu">MENU</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but it seems like this is probably the best/cleanest way of going about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can actually use something like this:

```
 .full-screen-menu {
   top: 50px;

   .header > #large-header > & {
     top: 100px;
   }
 }
```

just like putting an '&' before a nested selector appends it to the back of the parent selector, it works in reverse if you put it after a nested selector.  So when thats compiled to css the selector is `.header > #large-header > .full-screen-menu`

Comment: Big if true! I'm testing this right now, edit to follow.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in this particular case, but I think this is definitely a great thing to know about css that I didn't before!